# Fixing indices in a constraint of an optimization model

Tags: python, optimization, mathematical-optimization, gurobi, indices

I am solving a Mixed Integer Problem with Gurobi package in Python. The problem is I do not know how to fix indices i for a below constraint:

```
w(t) = x(t,i=1) - s(t,i=1) ∀t ∈ N
```

t and i are indices from different sets. I write the following code but it does not work. Could you please help me with it?

```
d =[18,7,6,5,10,1,8]
sh[1,2,3,4,5]

m=len(sh)
p=len(d)

for t in range(p):
    model.addConstr(w[t] == x[t, 1] - s[t,1])
```

I am going to write a code for the part i=1 but I can not. Writing even index.sh('1') does not help me.

I tried the written code but it shows an error. I am new to Python and need help to solve this issue

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. Please include some of your source code and show what you've tried and what you want to achieve. See [how to ask a good question](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Please look at the below listing. I have assumed that index `i`has only one element.

```
import gurobipy as gp
from gurobipy import GRB


d =[18,7,6,5,10,1,8]
sh = [1,2,3,4,5]

m=len(sh)
p=len(d)

model = gp.Model("")
w = model.addVars(p)

# assuming that length of the second index is 1
x = model.addVars(p, 1)
s = model.addVars(p, 1)

for t in range(p):
    model.addConstr(w[t] == x[t, 0] - s[t, 0])
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer. The zero you wrote refers to the index, am I right?

Comment: Yes, it is the second index, which has only one element. If my answer is useful, request you to please accept and upvote for general benefit. Reach back if you need more clarification.